# Load all constant value in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a constant class in Library and I can call one of them in controller, my question, how can I call all constant values of the class in controller?

```
class Enum {
    const One = '1';
    const Two= '2';
}
```

to use:

```
return Enum::One; // print '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest (albeit not necessarily the best) way would be to define them within an array as in

```
$const = array(
  'One'    => 1,
  'Two'    => 2,
);
```

Then you'd call them as `$const['One']`, `$const['Two']`, etc.

If these constants need to be available everywhere, you could set up a helper function that gets loaded on every controller that looks like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function get_constants()
{
    $const = array(
        'One'          => 1,
        'Two'          => 2,
        'Copyright'    => '2018. YourCompany, LLC',
        'Creator'      => 'Your name here',
    );

    return $const;
}
```

Load the helper everywhere and then you can just use it like this:

```
$constants = get_constants();
echo $constants['Creator']; // outputs 'Your name here'
```

There's more standard ways, but this is by far the easiest AFAIK